# Handle Multiple inheritance implementation containing same method. #Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, multiple-inheritance

I'm writing an implementation where a `class` and `interface` (both belongs to SDK) having same method name implementation(e.g. `getHeight()`).

**Stage-1**

No issue with Java. But with Kotlin it's throwing error:

> Class XYZ must override @ViewDebug.ExportedProperty public final fun
>   getHeight()

After few searching ended up with solution as suggested:

```
@ViewDebug.ExportedProperty public final fun getHeight(): Int {
        super<View>.getHeight()

        return 0
    }
```

**Stage-2**

But then it started throwing compilation error:

> 'getHeight'hides member of supertype 'View' and need 'override'
>   modifier

[image: ![enter image description here]

**Stage-3**

And if I go with `override` annotation then it gives error:

> 'getHeight'in 'View' is final and can not be overridden

[image]

Any pointers around how this can be fixed. Please note, method-classes are from SDK and can not be modified.

Comment: just quick question to clarify, why would you need to declare "public final" in your method in kotlin code, any method in a class should be "public" and final (not extendable/override) is the behavior of Kotlin class (except you declare your class as open class)?

Comment: true, that has added just using default hint given my IDE but can be removed. But original issue with multiple method from two different class(Java class) from SDK.

Comment: thanks for the reply, what the behavior of your current class implementation you would expect when having 2 same method signatures there? like 
```
yourObject.getHeight()
```
it would be from the SDK class OR the SDK interface (override by you)?

Comment: These are implementation method inside the SDK classes and at least it is not required in front class I'm implementing.